# Javascript/Jquery get child element, substract string and substitute

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, substr

I looked a lot, but I couldn't find a solution to my problem :c I'm not a JS expert, but this might be an easy one for programmers.

I have a list, a nav list:

```
<ul id="menu-navbar">
   <li id="menu-item-270-en" class="lang-item">
     <a href="site.com/en">
       English
     </a>
   </li>
   <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
     <a href="site.com/">
       Português
     </a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Two things:
I need to get the text (English) from `<a>` inside the `<li>`, subtract and return only the first 2 letters. I want the site to show **En**.
For the Português text, I want it to show **Pt** instead. A replace(); function should do, shouldn't it?

Can't insert neither id nor class into `<a>`, because it's generated by a plugin in Wordpress.

For the full code, the site is http://yogmel.com and the list on the upper right, on the navigation bar.

Note: The English site is not fully functional yet.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For you requirement, its better to maintain a mapping object instead.

#### jQuery

```js
var langListMap = [{
  text: "English",
  shortName: "En"
}, {
  text: "Português",
  shortName: "Pt"
}]

$(document).ready(function(){
  $.each($("a"), function(i,a){
    var sName = getObject($(a).text());
    if(sName){
      $(a).text(sName.shortName);
    }
  });
})

function getObject(text){
  console.log(text)
  return langListMap.filter(function(a){
    return a.text === text.trim();
  })[0]
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="menu-navbar">
  <li id="menu-item-270-en" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/en">
       English
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Português
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Test
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

#### Pure JS

```js
var langListMap = [{
  text: "English",
  shortName: "En"
}, {
  text: "Português",
  shortName: "Pt"
}]

function getObject(text) {
  return langListMap.filter(function(a) {
    return a.text === text.trim();
  })[0]
}

(function() {
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    var sName = getObject(a[i].innerHTML);
    if (sName) {
      a[i].innerHTML = sName.shortName;
    }
  }
})();
```

```html
<ul id="menu-navbar">
  <li id="menu-item-270-en" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/en">
       English
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Português
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Test
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for your answer!
Can you tell me how can I send these values back to HTML, instead of an alert? Instead of showing English | Português, it substitutes to En | Pt.
Thank you soooo much!

Comment: Do you mean, on click, set some element with `En`?

Comment: I mean, instead of user viewing this http://i.imgur.com/eDE5Umg.jpg
On document load, show this http://i.imgur.com/5gw9Yb9.jpg
I can't do this manually, because it's auto generated by a plugin :c that's why it has to be done with Javascript.
I don't want that the link has to be clicked to show the shortname, I want it to replace the text on HTML.
Thank you so much for your time Rajesh!

Comment: @yogmel I have updated my answer. Also I have added a pure JS version. Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Rajesh :) I'll also update the question for future searches.
Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

To use plain JavaScript for this, rather than using the jQuery library, I'd suggest:

```
'use strict'

// declaring the variable 'abbreviationsMap' as a 'constant'
// to prevent rebinding later in the script (although it can
// still be updated, eg:
// abbreviationsMap.English = 'xy', or
// abbreviationsMap.Welsh = 'cy'
const abbreviationsMap = {
  'English': 'En',
  'Português': 'Pt'
};


// named function to handle the creation of abbreviations,
// with user-supplied options:
function abbreviations(opts) {

  // declaring variables using 'let' to limit the
  // variables to the scope of the block in which
  // they're declared:
  let settings = {

    // the CSS selector by which the elements whose
    // content should be abbreviated should be selected:
    'selector': '.toAbbreviate',

    // the map of full-words-to-abbreviations to use:
    'abbreviations': abbreviationsMap
  };

  // iterating over the properties declared in the
  // opts Object to update the settings:
  for (let property in opts) {

    // if the opts Object has a named property
    // not inherited from its prototype equal to
    // the current property-name:
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {

      // we update the same property of the
      // settings Object to match the value
      // from the opts Object:
      settings[ property ] = opts[ property ];
    }
  }

  // finding the elements from the document that match the
  // CSS selector:
  let elements = document.querySelectorAll( settings.selector );

  // converting that NodeList to an Array, using Array.from():
  let elementsArray = Array.from( elements );

  // iterating over the Array:
  elementsArray.forEach(function(abbr) {
    // 'abbr' the first-named argument of the anonymous function
    // is automatically supplied by the function itself, and is
    // a reference to the array-element of the array over which
    // we're iterating.

    // setting the title property of the array-element to
    // offer an explanation of what the abbreviation means,
    // removing any leading/trailing white-space using
    // String.prototype.trim():
    abbr.title = abbr.textContent.trim();

    // updating the textContent of the element to match the
    // abbreviation held in the settings.abbreviation Array,
    // or, if that's a falsy value, simply returns the title
    // of the element:
    abbr.textContent = settings.abbreviations[abbr.title] || abbr.title;

  });

}

// calling the function, and modifying the CSS selector
// to be used within the function:
abbreviations({
  'selector': '.lang-item a'
});
```

```js
'use strict'

const abbreviationsMap = {
  'English': 'En',
  'Português': 'Pt'
};

function abbreviations(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'selector': '.toAbbreviate',
    'abbreviations': abbreviationsMap
  };

  for (let property in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty( property )) {
      settings[property] = opts[ property ];
    }
  }

  let elements = document.querySelectorAll( settings.selector );
  let elementsArray = Array.from( elements );

  elementsArray.forEach(function( abbr ) {
    abbr.title = abbr.textContent.trim();
    abbr.textContent = settings.abbreviations[ abbr.title ] || abbr.title;

  });

}

abbreviations({
  'selector': '.lang-item a'
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu-navbar">
  <li id="menu-item-270-en" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/en">
       English
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Português
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-cy" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/cy">
       Welsh
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kdg6up2s/).

Alternatively, another approach is:

```
'use strict'

// again, a named function to convert the textContent
// of relevant items into an abbreviated form:
function abbreviations(opts) {

  let settings = {
    // the CSS selector with which the elements should
    // be selected
    'selector': '.toAbbreviate',

    // the property of the element, or its ancestor element,
    // from which the abbreviation should be derived:
    'property': 'id',

    // the regular expression by which the abbreviation
    // should be derived,
    // this is looking for a sequence of lower-case 
    // alphabetical characters in the range from 'a' to 'z'
    // ('[a-z]') inclusive, that's two characters in length
    // ('{2}') and occurs at the end of the property-string
    // ('$'):
    'regexp': /[a-z]{2}$/
  };

  for (let property in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      settings[property] = opts[property];
    }
  }

  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(settings.selector);
  let elementsArray = Array.from(elements),
    text;

  elementsArray.forEach(function(abbr) {

    // finding the closest ancestor element to the current
    // element that has the property identified in the
    // settings.property value, using CSS attribute-selector
    // syntax (identifying an 'id' property/attribute by '[id]'
    // for example;
    // accesing the property identified by the settings.property
    // value of the found element, retrieving the 'id' by:
    // HTMLElement[ id ], 
    // and retrieving the portion of the property-value
    // that matches the settings.regexp property-value,
    // (or null if there is no match):
    text = abbr.closest('[' + settings.property + ']')[settings.property].match(settings.regexp);

    // because null is a possible result, we check
    // that the text variable exists:
    if (text) {

      // if it does, then we retrieve the match
      // held at the first index of the returned
      // Array:
      text = text[0];
    } else {

      // otherwise we simply use the trimmed text-content:
      text = abbr.textContent.trim();
    }

    // setting the title of the element:
    abbr.title = abbr.textContent.trim();

    // capitalising the first character of the String and
    // concatenating that with the rest of the String:
    abbr.textContent = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  });

}

abbreviations({
  'selector': '.lang-item a'
});
```

```js
'use strict'

function abbreviations(opts) {
  let settings = {
    'selector': '.toAbbreviate',
    'property': 'id',
    'regexp': /[a-z]{2}$/
  };

  for (let property in opts) {
    if (opts.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
      settings[property] = opts[property];
    }
  }

  let elements = document.querySelectorAll(settings.selector);
  let elementsArray = Array.from(elements),
    text;

  elementsArray.forEach(function(abbr) {
    text = abbr.closest('[' + settings.property + ']')[settings.property].match(settings.regexp);
    if (text) {
      text = text[0];
    } else {
      text = abbr.textContent.trim();
    }
    abbr.title = abbr.textContent.trim();
    abbr.textContent = text.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + text.slice(1);
  });

}

abbreviations({
  'selector': '.lang-item a'
});
```

```html
<ul id="menu-navbar">
  <li id="menu-item-270-en" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/en">
       English
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-pt" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/">
       Português
     </a>
  </li>
  <li id="menu-item-270-cy" class="lang-item">
    <a href="site.com/cy">
       Welsh
     </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/kdg6up2s/1/).